# How to install aptana 3 as a plugin for myeclipse 10.1

Tags: html, aptana3, myeclipse

I now use MyEclipse 10.1 version for web development, now I need want to install aptana 3.2 as a plugin for MyEclipse, and I successfully installed aptana 2 using "MyEclipse Configure Center --> Software". How to update it to 3.2 or latest version for supporting HTML5 tags?